# LINQ to XML: How to rearrange the query?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have the code that works:

XML:

```
<parameters>
    <company>asur_nsi</company>
    <password>lapshovva</password>
    <user>dogm_LapshovVA</user>
</parameters>
```

Code:

```
XElement documentRoot = XElement.Load(webConfigFilePath);
var param = from p in documentRoot.Descendants("parameters")
            select new
            {
                company = p.Element("company").Value,
                password = p.Element("password").Value,
                user = p.Element("user").Value
            };

foreach (var p in param)
{
    AuthContext ac = new AuthContext()
    {
        Company = p.company,
        Password = p.password,
        User = p.user
    };
}
```

But, I'd like to make it better and shorter and want to return the object of AuthContext type immediately. I want to move creation of AuthContext object to "select new" section in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XElement documentRoot = XElement.Load(webConfigFilePath);
var param = from p in documentRoot.Descendants("parameters")
            select new AuthContext()
            {
                Company = p.Element("company").Value,
                Password = p.Element("password").Value,
                User = p.Element("user").Value
            };
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just figured it out as well. But, I forgot to write I need to return the object of AuthContext type, not var.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement documentRoot = XElement.Load(webConfigFilePath);
var authContexts = (from p in documentRoot.Descendants("parameters")
            select new AuthContext
            {
                Company = p.Element("company").Value,
                Password = p.Element("password").Value,
                User = p.Element("user").Value
            }).ToArray();
```

Just create `AuthContext` instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: Thank you. I've just figured it out as well. But, I forgot to write I need to return the object of AuthContext type, not var.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me. I've just figured it out how to do what I wanted:

```
var config = XElement.Load(webConfigFilePath).Descendants("parameters").Single();
AuthContext ac = new AuthContext
{
    Company = config.Element("company").Value,
    Password = config.Element("password").Value,
    User = config.Element("user").Value
};
```

Thank you anyway.